# Ansible stop playbook if file present

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to stop a playbook during his execution if a define file is present on my node and also output to explain why the playbook has stopped?

It is to prevent an accidental re-execution of my playbook on a node that has my application already installed because I generate a password during this install and I don't want to reinitialise this password.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [fail module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html) to force a failure with a custom failure message.

Couple this with a check for a file, using the [stat module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html), and this should work easily enough for you.

A quick example or a one run playbook might look something like this:

```
- name: check for foo.conf
  stat: path=/etc/foo.conf
  register: foo

- name: fail if already run on host
  fail: msg="This host has already had this playbook run against it"
  when: foo.stat.exists

- name: create foo.conf
  file: path=/etc/foo.conf state=touch
```

Comment: after testing the code it doesn't work, I have this message (I continue searching on my side):
FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'foo.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (foo.exists): 'dict object' has no attribute 'exists'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_5__safetyportal/Safety_Cube_master/main.yml': line 12, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: fail if already run on host\n    ^ here\n"}

Comment: with the '.stat.exists' it works fine thanks for you help (can you edit your comment to correct it ?)